# How do I dynamically wrap a document in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a webpage that does not use Iframes. Like:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body >...(content)</body>
</html>
```

And I want to write a piece of code that gives me the following outcome:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body >
        <iframe>...(content)</iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try something at all? some what you have done (code) maybe?

Comment: I did what has been mentioned in the first answer, but ran into a different issue. There seems to be an iframe inside the "content". This disappears when I wrap the "content" with an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
while (document.body.childNodes.length > 0) { 
    iframe.appendChild(document.body.childNodes[0]);
}
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the first div inside the body

e.g 
     **HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="inner">ALL contents</div>
</body>
 </html>

 **jquery**

$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<iframe></iframe>" );
```